# Which AWS service should I use to host a Ghost CMS blog?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs, ghost-blog

I would like to setup a simple Ghost personal blog.  However with so many options on AMS, it's not easy to to pick the best one.  For me, best means lower cost & management possibly at the expense of performance and flexibility.

I currently have an expressjs/mongo db app running on Lightsail (nothing special, build ground up and used as a VPS), for about $10/month.  I could provision another instance and install there.

Another option is EC2, which I believe is similar to Lightsail but with flexibility/options.

I've also heard about elastic beanstalk being popular for nodejs apps (like ghost).

Most likely there are even other options like lambdas with s3 and dynamodb, however that might be be more challenging to setup and could have a maintenance cost.

It's also likely that with so many options AWS provides, there's another I've not considered.

Answer (score 2):

If you're happy with Lightsail stick with that. EC2 is more flexible but MUCH more complex and it's also more expensive. I don't think any of the other AWS services would be worth your time, Beanstalk is fine but takes more knowledge and work and isn't really required for a simple blog unless it's super high volume. Start simple. Lightsale.